# Duplicate Results in Oracle SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When I run the script below, I keep getting duplicate results, even when using `distinct`.

```
select distinct 
a.SDT, a.fNo, b.IDType, b.pNo, b.pfName, b.plName, b.PDoB, b.Street, b.City, c.Phone  
from Scheduled_Flight a, Passenger b, pass_Phone c
where fNo = '0000021'
and
a.SDT = '08-sep-2017 17:30';
```

[image: Duplicates in Oracle]
I am new to SQL and any help would be much appreciated into solving this issue.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Without proper conditions for your joins you have essentially created a cross join, resulting in a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Have a look at [other joins](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj29840.html).

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: please replace the image by text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I keep getting duplicate results, even when using distinct"

You are not getting duplicates in your result set. Rather you have a Cartesian product which is a combination of ONE flight, THREE passengers and THREE phone numbers. Each record in the set is unique so `distinct` doesn't have any affect.

The problem is you have no join conditions in your `from` clause. There should be a column on `passenger` which is the foreign key on `flight`, and a column on `pass_phone` which is the foreign key on `passenger`.

It is easy to fix: you just need to join the tables. Assuming your data model is consistent, your query should look like this (and you don't need DISTINCT):

```
select a.SDT, a.fNo, b.IDType, b.pNo, b.pfName, b.plName, b.PDoB, b.Street, b.City,c.Phone  
from Scheduled_Flight a
      join Passenger b on b.fNo = a.fNo
      join pass_Phone c on c.pNo = b.bNo
where a.fNo = '0000021'
and a.SDT = '08-sep-2017 17:30';
```

However, I notice that in your version of the query you didn't prefix `fNo`. That makes me think you don't have a column of that name on `passenger` (otherwise the query would have failed on `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`). So, either the foreign key columns are named differently or you haven't got them.

---

> "Is it possible to specify only the date without the time?"

Yep. Use an [ANSI date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51049) e.g. `date '2017-09-08'`

> "Is it possible to specify only the date without the time to still produce results from the database?"

That depends on the how the data is stored. Oracle dates are stored with a time element. If no time is specified (or the time element is truncated) then the time element defaults to midnight. This often catches beginners out, for instance because the pseudo-column sysdate returns the current date *and* time, not just the current date.

So, if you know the dates are stored in your table without a time element you can do this:

```
where a.sdt = date '2017-09-08'
```

But if you don't know that, you can truncate ...

```
where trunc(a.sdt) = date '2017-09-08'
```

or test for a range

```
where a.sdt >= date '2017-09-08'
and  a.sdt < date '2017-09-09'
```

---

> "How come the following code is still producing duplicate results?

```
select distinct r.sNo, r.tCode, s.fNo, s.SDT 
from Airplane r, Scheduled_Flight s 
where SDT >= SYSDATE -1;
```

> The airplane attribute cannot have the s.SDT attribute."

Without seeing the output I can't be sure but I would bet that this query does not produce duplicate records either. What you have is a product combining all your AIRPLANE records with all your FLIGHT records matching the `sdt` filter.

This is another data modelling problem. Of course aeroplanes don't have a flight time: one aeroplane makes many flights. But it makes perfect sense for a flight to be assigned to a plane. In fact that's crucial to ensuring that you don't have more flights than you have planes to fly them, and that one plane isn't planned to take off from London for Madrid at a time when it's planned to be half-way to Hong Kong.

You really should use the ANSI 92 syntax, as I showed in my answer to your previous posted code. The explicit joins not only make it easier to understand the query but they prevent mistakes like this. The fact that you apparently don't have any candidate columns to make the join immediately highlights the flaw in the data model.

```
select distinct r.sNo, r.tCode, s.fNo, s.SDT 
from Airplane r
    INNER JOIN  Scheduled_Flight s ON ???? 
where SDT >= SYSDATE -1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify only the date without the time to still produce results from the database?

Comment: so distinct does not work for cartesian joins? That is wrong.

Comment: @miracle173 - not sure what point you're trying to make. `distinct` guarantees that the result set comprises a set of unique rows. A Cartesian product is a result set which comprises one row for each *combination* of rows. Each row in a Cartesian product may be unique, if so `distinct` won't make any difference.

Comment: @APC Howcome the following code is still producing duplicate results?   select distinct  r.sNo, r.tCode, s.fNo, s.SDT
from Airplane r, Scheduled_Flight s
 where SDT >= SYSDATE -1;   The airplane attribute cannot have the s.SDT attribute.

Comment: The OP asks why he gets duplicate results when using distinct and you answer the reason is that he has no join condition. That is wrong. The resultset of the cartesian join in your demo does not contain duplicates even if you omit the distinct.

Comment: @miracle173 - I know it's difficult to read screenshots but the OP's result set **does not contain duplicates**.  It comprises NINE unique records produced from ONE flight, THREE passengers and THREE phones. My original example reflected the OP's situation. However, I have revised the demo to show the different behaviour when the product comes from tables with unique records and duplicated records. [Enjoy](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/fjiz1ytngqntbrndbk529yj5x)

Comment: I see that you added a remark to your post that the resultset doesn't contain duplicates and so I removed the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

i don't see any rows which are duplicated, if you compare every column of each row, each row is uniquely identified, since you are doing cartesian product you are getting multiple records. but each rows are unique to each other.